# CSS Animation: why does it not work in firefox when generated by autoprefixer

Tags: css, html, autoprefixer

I am using autoprefixer and think that keyframes in firefox dont have to be prefixed. (Using latest FF38)

My original CSS

```css
.blinking-cursor {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #2E3D48;
  animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes "blink" {
  from, to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="blinking-cursor">|</span>
```

Generated CSS by autoprefixer

```css
.blinking-cursor {
  display:block;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #2E3D48;
  -webkit-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
  animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
}
@keyframes "blink" {
  from, to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes "blink" {
  from, to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="blinking-cursor">|</span>
```

Then why does the cursor not animate while it animates if `-moz` was used http://codepen.io/ArtemGordinsky/pen/GnLBq

Comment: It works for me too using Chromium. In your post there is only -webkit-animation. That wil work only for webkit browsers.

Comment: @yakutsa you are using which FF on which platform? I am on Fedora(Linux)

Comment: @drive235 as far as I know autoprefixer would have added moz if it found it necessary. But FF does not need moz anymore after FF 16

Comment: @MeghParikh ok, true - confirmed: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: I cannot get it to work @yakutsa are you sure you are using FF on which platform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes `"` around the animation names in your keyframes declaration. The animation name is an identifier, and not a string.

```
@keyframes "blink" {
  from, to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}
```